# How can I maintain photo color consistency across computer monitors?

Tags: photoshop, display-calibration, monitors

When saving photos for the web from within Photoshop I run into issue where my colors are not consistent between monitors. While I understand there will be some difference between monitors there are at times a huge difference between my desktop monitor and my laptop monitor. In the best cases the colors (on my laptop monitor) are a bit washed out but not to bad in worst cases the colors are completely different shades and the picture is not blown out but close. If I adjust the colors on my desktop monitor to compensate for my laptop monitor the colors (majority of the time) are way to dark. Are there any tips/tricks on maintaining consistency across monitors?

A few notes: I always save my photos for web using Photoshop's `Save for Web and Devices` below is a screenshot of my settings. (I have un-checked Embed Color Profile would that help?) I have calibrated both monitors as best as possible with software. (I am not using any form of hardware calibration.) And the monitor for my desktop is an old LCD monitor. (It is at least 6 years old but was not in use for at least 2-3 years of that 6.) The laptop is a new computer. (Is age going to be playing into this issue?) And finally neither monitor is a "Glossy" monitor.

[image: Photoshop Save for Web and Devices Settings]

Comment: Lynda, does http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/16350/what-software-shows-the-most-accurate-version-of-a-photograph-for-web-viewing help?

Comment: @mattdm - Thanks for the link, there is some good information there. It may help though I am not sure.

Comment: @mattdm - One difference between that question and mine is the colors look consistent no matter where the image is if I stay on the same monitor. It is when I go from monitor one to monitor two that the changes happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the basic answer here is: you need to get a hardware-based calibration device and use that on both monitors. As you have experienced, it's really hard to get this right by eye. Getting the monitors calibrated correctly will help, but if one or both of them are really poor equipment, you still may have limitations.

We've got some questions and answers on how to do this (and what to do it with) in the [`display-calibration`](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/display-calibration?sort=faq&pagesize=50) tag.

You're already saving the image in the limited and "safe" sRGB color space, so there's really very little more you can do to the image itself.

Comment: I believe you are right. Thanks for your help and information.