# Calibrating monitor for editing photos for publishing on web

Tags: photo-editing, color-management, white-balance, color-correction

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What software shows the most accurate version of a photograph for web viewing?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/16350/what-software-shows-the-most-accurate-version-of-a-photograph-for-web-viewing)

I have a [bunch of photos taken in rather difficult lighting conditions](https://plus.google.com/photos/100214531380417392802/albums/5730143125071016801) and I am trying to make them look as good as possible for online publishing. (that is, I want to upload them on my webpage and to Google+).

I do not have control over the color profile of the screens of people who will be viewing my photos. Therefore, I guess I need do match the "common denominator" as best as I can. And edit the picture in a way that will look reasonably good on most consumer devices people use.

Is there some "most common" color profile for consumer grade monitors or advice on how to tone the pictures to look reasonably well almost everywhere?

Comment: Although the question I marked as a duplicate comes in from a different angle, I think [my answer there](http://photo.stackexchange.com/a/16356/1943) (which is in the basic substance the same as what @Rob gives here) covers your situation pretty much exactly.

Comment: If I had found that question before, I wouldn't have asked this. But in Rob's answer, there is quite valuable link that addresses the fact that people often mess with brightness and contrast settings on their monitors and a method how to deal with it. So please do not close this, maybe some more good answers will come up. Also, this question is valuable from SEO perspective, because it has the word calibrate in the title, which is something that people interested in this topic may well use in their query

Comment: Don't overlook resolution. http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_resolution_higher.asp - If you think most people will be viewing in these resolutions then be sure to factor this in - if light box is an option use this to help.

Comment: Questions that are marked as duplicates are not deleted, for exactly the reason you mention. They stay around but with clear pointers to the "canonical" question, so we get the best of both worlds.

Comment: Also: the search engine here is terrible, so there's no shame in not finding a similar older question, especially if it was asked using slightly different terms.

Answer (score 4):

This is an interesting question and I am glad you addressed the part about people having different setups

The "common denominator" as you call it for me would be sRGB ICC and [this article](http://www.color.org/srgb.xalter) Titled **A Standard Default Color Space for the Internet: sRGB** backs that theory up.

Use sRGB in your workflow and you should cover most bases

Hope this helps